# Admin bar doesn't appear on the front-end of a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I have a WordPress installation in a subdomain (http://base.example.com), but I want users to access the front-end from (http://www.example.com). The subdomain is a subfolder within the root of the site. I have copied `index.php` and `.htaccess` to the root of my site and changed the path in `index.php` to point to my subdomain. The website works fine, both the front-end and back-end, but when I login and go to the front-end, I cannot see the admin bar, and it appears as if I am logged out. When I go to `wp-admin`, I see the admin bar, and I can preform all administration functions as needed. How do I fix this problem so I can see the admin bar on the front-end?

Comment: Sounds like you need to clear your cache. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I've already empty my cache. I think I need a specific .htaccess rule. I don't know if the issue came from a htaccess wrong configuration but I suppose that.

Comment: please see my answer. It is pretty detailed, but I believe it will fix your issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: please see my most recent edit. I believe that this will work for you.

Comment: this issue was solved by empty the cache with the plugin from EDIT 2 (see the next answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 2:

You should be able to resolve your issues using the plugin [root Cookie](https://wordpress.org/plugins/root-cookie/). It hasn't been updated in 2 years, but it will fix the problem that you're having. You need the login/authentication cookie to be accessible across subdomains. Follow these directions:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Enable subdomain support in plugin settings.
3. Logout of the WordPress admin.
4. Login again and check if it works.

The reason that this issue occurs is because when WordPress sets the cookie that says you're logged in, it sets it for the administration domain. That means, when you visit from the non-administration domain, the cookie isn't allowed to be used for authentication due to browser security. This plugin changes the URL for the cookie to allow for use across subdomains, which allows for you to see the admin bar on the front-end.

Comment: @mungle WordPress and caching shouldn't be applicable in this question. The home URL is where WordPress' core files are stored, not where the user should be visting. What error do you receive when you try my edit?

Comment: as I explained in my question:
- if I visit example.com I'm not logged-in and there is not admin bar
- if I visit base.example.com I'm logged-in and I can see the admin bar.
In settings:
My site url is http://base.example.com;
My home url is http://example.com

Comment: I was unable to login... (answer to your last comment) and in settings I have both site and home url with http://base.example.org

Comment: @mungle check out my most recent edit, I think that will solve your problem!

Comment: Success...It worked...!!!!!! Why that happens? I tried with other two computers to be sure my cache wasn't hold some information about my login... I tried private navigations... how it has been fixed? why? and over all, as this plugin looks old, should I still have it active? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @mungle GREAT! :) I'm glad that it was able to work! I'm going to update my question with why it occurs so it can be of use to others in the future. Even though the plugin is old, it works fine and should be safe to keep active.

Comment: Hello @michaelrmcneill...! The website looks it work in the right way but I'm still getting some issue which came from bad redirects... Just a question: could you provide me the .htaccess configurations for my root and my subdomain directory? I think I need to make some adjustments also there...

Comment: You'll need to post another question for me to help you out. If you post a link to the other question, I'll be glad to help you out!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820174/wordpress-in-base-example-com-and-accessible-from-example-com-give-me-path-issue Thanks ;-)

Comment: 2019 and still relevant. Awesome, thank you so much!